# Silverlight: Two-way Binding for a DependencyProperty (IList) not working

Tags: silverlight, binding, silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties, two-way-binding

Well..its working BUT only when user creates a property that is of type List.

Here's the complete scenario.

I have a templated control (Multi Select ComboBox with Checkboxes)
User gives a List/ObservableCollection as its ItemsSource. The collection can be of any type (Employee, Chair, Person etc). The DependencyProperty for ItemsSource is of Type IList.

User can also give a List with two-way binding in a DependencyProperty called SelectedItems (so that he can show some items as checked and get back the items which gets checked)

Now the issue is with the SelectedItems dp. It is of type IList in the templated control.
The two-way binding does not work if user has bind it to, say, `List<Person>`.
But it works if `List<Person>` is changed to `List<object>`.

I cant figure out what is it that I am not doing right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to place a TwoWay binding on the `SelectedItems` property.  This would imply that the control should create and assign an instance of an object implementing `IList` to the property on the source object.  However there is no way for control to know what actual type to create to assign to the property.

Instead you should be using a OneWay bind to a List that pre-exists in the source object albeit an empty one.  The controls task then is to simply add or remove members in that list from the list supplied in the `ItemsSource` property.

Comment: But will a OneWay Binding update the source when I will add/remove members to the list in the control?

Comment: @James:  Yes.  The implementation IList assigned to the SelectedItems would be an existing list held by the source.  In fact the property of the source that you bind to the SelectedItems could be ReadOnly.  The source creates the instance of the list internally and exposes it on that readonly property.  Any changes to that list made by the control would be directly on the list held by the source.

Comment: yes..adding members directly from the ItemsSource property to the SelectedItems is working great..the changes are reflected back to the source :) ..however the doubt I have is "The source creates the instance of the list internally" ( user needs to make sure that the binded list in source must not be null). Then how is the SelectedItems property of ListBox (for multiSelection mode) works? I dont think it requires the user to create an instance of the property? [Plz let me know if I am wrong or not making sense!]

Comment: @James:  You quite right you're not making sense.  Its difficult when you use terms like "instance of the property" to really see what is you aren't understanding.  Your control __cannot__ be responsilbe for creating a `List<T>` where it does not know the type of T.  It therefore __must__ be supplied with an existing instance created inside the source object.

Comment: "instance of the property" equals "It therefore must be supplied with an existing instance created inside the source object"..your made your point quite crisp and clear..thanks for your help!

Comment: Was creating same control and had same problem :)